# Ищу безопасный randomAlphanumeric

Tags: java

Подскажите, в какой Java библиотеке есть функции для безопасной генерации случайных букво-цифровых стрингов?

Пока я нашел `org.apache.commons.lang.RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric`.
Результат выглядит именно так как мне нужно, однако внутри она использует обычный небезопасный `java.util.Random`, а мне нужно побезопаснее, например `java.security.SecureRandom`.

Comment: неочень поняен, что именно нужно. не могли бы описать подробнее, нажав на править?

Comment: что значит безопасной генерации?